# HTML content in an iPhone app

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone

I am currently developing an iPhone app showing the contents of sports related articles available in my website. Each article contains one title, one picture and some content. When I refer to the content I include the text of the article, the youtube videos that can be here or not, the link refering to other articles that are or are not in my website (depending on the article) etc...

In the first version of my app I had two screens. The first one was a customized UITableView looking like this :

[image]

Then when I clicked on an article I had the article open up in a second screen like this :

[image]

I retrieve all of the data I need by calling a PHP file that it making a MySQL request to my server's database and then sending the data back to my app via JSON. The problem I have is that the content of the article is given in HTML and I cannot parse it so it can be dynamically used. For instance when there is a link to a website I'd like to have it clickable. When there is an embeded youtube video I'd like it to be viewable inside of my app. In order to accomplish that do I have to use a UIWebView ? (Note that I don't want to show the article page from the website directly into the app. I want to be able to customize it anyway I want).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take take the HTML content from your JSON.  If you have valid HTML, you can simply load it in a UIWebView in your view using the following call:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Short of writing your own HTML parser, this is you best bet.  So you view can have static UIImageView and UILabels for the title and image, and a webview that will display your HTML (which can be customized however you'd like).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @wottle ! I'll try that ASAP.